# I do not know how this method is not getting execute

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (notification) {
        NSLog(@"app recieved notification from remote%@",notification);
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)notification];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"app did not recieve notification");
    }
```

here I am getting app did not receive notification method why ?

Comment: that is NOT how you ask proper question, show some code, are there actually any notifications, provide a LOT more detail.

Comment: (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{ NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);}

Comment: (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{ NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);} I called it and printed also value of userinfo but after some time  it is not getting execute

Comment: Do not add your code to comments. Update your question with relevant details.

Comment: UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (notification) {
        NSLog(@"app recieved notification from remote%@",notification);
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)notification];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"app did not recieve notification");
    }
In above method I am getting output as app did not receive notification why?

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to consult Apple's documentation first when it comes to their SDK.

Having a look here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/

You will see this extract:

> When a remote notification arrives, the system calls the
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
>   method. Notifications usually signal the availability of new
>   information. In your app delegate method, you might begin downloading
>   new data from a server so that you can update your app’s data
>   structures. You might also use the notification to update your user
>   interface.

If you're not using Push notifications, but local notifications, then you need this method: `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`

The reason the method does not get executed is due to not receiving a remote notification.

Comment: ya I know it is not receving notification  but why I am not getting it

Comment: Does the notification arrive but the method not called or does the notification just not arrive? If the latter - you need to be looking at the APN side of things and not the app.

Comment: NSDictionary *apnsBody = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (apnsBody) {
        // Do your code with apnsBody
        NSLog(@"%@apnsbody",apnsBody);
    }
        else{
            NSLog(@"nullvalue");
        } I am getting null value for apnsbody why?